# how to calculate unique column values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my data

```
cardNo| userName| tablename| hours |  date 
1     |  a      |    a     |   12  |  12-06-2015 
1     |  a      |    a     |    5  |  11-06-2015 
2     |  b      |    b     |    3  |  15-06-2015 
1     |  a      |    a     |    8  |  12-06-2015 
2     |  b      |    b     |    3  |  21-06-2015 
1     |  a      |    a     |   12  |  14-06-2015 
2     |  b      |    b     |   10  |  8-06-2015
```

`cardNo` is unique. I need to display all details and total hours for each card, like:

```
cardNo | userName | tablename | totalhours 
1      | a        |   a       |  37 
2      | b        |   b       |  16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT cardNo,userName, tablename, sum(hours) hours
FROM Table_1 GROUP BY cardNo,userName,tablename

Answer (score 4):

It's simple `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT cardNo,sum(hours) 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY cardNo;
```

*I left it as an exercise for the OP to include userName and tablename columns into the query*

Comment: Thank you very much, how to fetch all table details using php.

Comment: Please anyone help us for this

Comment: @BalaMurugan, you should post a new question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476642/php-mysql-code-needed This is the link for latest post vhu, thanks advance