# How to "SUM" unique column values and filter by date

Tags: php, mysql

**INPUT**

```
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|     cardNo | userName | tablename | hours |    date     |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+
|          1 | a        | a         |    12 | 12-06-2015  |
|          1 | a        | a         |     5 | 11-06-2015  |
|          2 | b        | b         |     3 | 15-06-2015  |
|          1 | a        | a         |     8 | 12-06-2015  |
|          2 | b        | b         |     3 | 21-06-2015  |
|          1 | a        | a         |    12 | 14-06-2015  |
|          2 | b        | b         |    10 | 8-06-2015   |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

cardNo is unique. I need to display all details and total hours for each card, like:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| cardNo | userName | tablename | totalhours  |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | a        | a         |         37  |
|      2 | b        | b         |         16  |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

**MY QUERY**

```
SELECT cardNo,sum(hours) 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY cardNo;
```

But I need totalHours >=20 are 'N'.

```
SELECT cardNo,sum(hours) 
FROM yourtable where totalHours>=20
GROUP BY cardNo;
```

I can't get correct answer. If I specify totalHours>=1 it gives correct answer; what can I do? And also I need PHP fetch code for that query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT cardNo,sum(hours) as TotalHours
FROM yourtable
WHERE date  BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
GROUP BY cardNo
HAVING sum(hours) >=20
```

Using WHERE clause, you can get the total hours of each cardNo between those dates.

Comment: and i need to check date. date >='N' and date<='N'

Comment: @BalaMurugan: Updated my answer. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you very much it is perfectly working... Raging Bull